# High performance calculation of least squares difference from all possible combinations (n lists)

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, combinations, least-squares

I'm looking for a very efficient way to calculate all possible combinations from n lists and then keep the combination with the smallest least squares difference.

I already have a code that does it, but when it gets to several million combinations things get slow.

**candidates_len** contains a list of lists with lengths i.e. [[500, 490, 510, 600][300, 490, 520][305, 497, 515]]
**candidates_name** contains a list of lists with names i.e. [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']['mi', 'mu', 'ma']['pi', 'pu', 'pa']]

Both lists have **n** lists.

```
#    Creating the possible combinations and store the lists of lengths in vector r
r=[[]]
for x in candidates_len:
    r = [ i + [y] for y in x for i in r ]
#Storing the names of the combinations and store the lists of identifiers in vector z
z=[[]]
for x in candidates_name:
    z = [ i + [y] for y in x for i in z ]          
#Calculating distances and storing the minimum one
min_index = 0
min_dist = 0
list_best = []
for index, item in enumerate(r):
    n = 0
    dist = 0
    while n < len(candidates_len):
        for i in range(n,len(candidates_len)):
            dist = dist + (item[n]-item[i])**2
        n=n+1
    if index==0:
            min_dist = dist
            min_index = index
            list_best.append(item)
    elif dist < min_dist:
        min_dist = dist
        min_index = index
        list_best = []
        list_best.append(z[index])
least_combination = min_index
```

A hard case:
http://pastebin.com/BkVQTQWK

Here are some test times. Would be good to get under a minute or so. I don't know if it's possible though.

> ```
> combinations time(s)
> 77760   1.255663
> 41184   1.580333
> 69120   6.214786
> 8960   1.131834
> 537600  14.855361
> 89100   1.264126
> 16384   3.247404
> 4199040 666.853284
> 226800   3.935878
> 9289728 679.064149
> ```

Comment: So what's the desired output for the example you give?

Comment: consider writting this in c++.. you will almost always get better performance

Comment: First, are the setup loops supposed to be generating the cartesian product of `candidates_len` with itself and likewise `candidates_name`? If so, there are much more direct ways to do that—but the simplest is just to call `itertools.product(*candidates_len)` (and wrap it in `list` if you need a list at the end).

Comment: @Paladin: Really, you think iterating over large collections of variable-sized lists is something that C++ does really well?

Comment: What's your current run time for several million combinations? What would you consider to be acceptable performance?

Comment: @NPE The desired output would be the combination (one item from each list) with lower score in least squares distance. ['b', 'mu', 'pu'] for the example.
In the code I implemented I get a number since I store all the possible combinations in a list. Not sure is the most efficient way.

Comment: Why are you doing `list_best = []` followed by `list_best.append(z[index])` instead of just `list_best=[z[index]]`? Or, for that matter, why is `list_best` a list in the first place, considering that you never put more than one element into it? It looks like you've tried to implement an algorithm from pseudocode you didn't quite understand; it might be easier to show us the original pseudocode.

Comment: @abarnert well, I have pretty good experiences with STL vector class :)

Comment: @abarnert That's because originally I kept a list with the best results, not only the best one. I should probably correct that.

Comment: @Paladin: There are things `vector` is good at, and things it isn't. Dealing with huge jagged 2D arrays is not one of them. The cache locality sucks. A naive implementation in C++ will probably be _worse_ than a naive implementation in Python.

Comment: Can you post the test data so we can compare other implementations to see if they're faster than yours?

Comment: @abarnert That's going to be difficult, since I get the data from a python class I made. Maybe I can extract a big case and post them as list?

Comment: Sounds perfect. In fact, having it as a list I can parse just by calling `import` probably makes it easier. Just post it at `pastebin` or somewhere.

Comment: I updated the post with some test data in pastebin, I didn't know about it BTW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first thought here is that you're spending an awful lot of time building up lists that you don't need. At the very least, scrapping them would make things a lot simpler, but no guarantees it would actually make things faster:

```
r = itertools.product(*candidates_len)
z = itertools.product(*candidates_name)

min_dist = None
for item, names in itertools.izip(r, z):
  dist = 0
  for n in range(len(item)):
    for i in range(n, len(item)):
      dist += (item[n]-item[i])**2
  if min_dist is None or dist < min_dist:
    min_dist = dist
    best = item, names

print(best)
```

With your test data, the explicit lists are taking up gigabytes of memory. I'm not sure how much—my poor 4GB laptop went into swap thrash hell before it even finished generating the `z` list, and everything slowed to a crawl. The whole operation takes less time with `itertools` than just the setup part without it… That probably isn't true on a machine with, say, 16GB of RAM, but still, why use the memory if you don't need it?

My next thought is that all you're doing is calculating the LSD on a bunch of arrays. Do you have a huge array of tiny arrays? If so, can you de-jagged them (e.g., filling them out with None) and `numpy` the whole thing? On the other hand, if it's an array of big arrays, you probably want a list (or, as above, an iterator) of `numpy` arrays, so at least you can vectorize one dimension.

Either way, vectorization is the key to optimizing anything that involves simple operations over big arrays, and `numpy` will often do vectorization better than anything an expert C++-and-Fortran-and-platform-specific-assembly coder is likely to do manually.

Without either thinking through the code or trying to understand the algorithm at a deep level, my first attempt would be to generate `r` as a sequence (as in my code above) but of `numpy` row vectors (something like `matrix(x, dtype=int) for x in itertools.product(*candidates_len)`). Then you can calculate the differences on each `item` by just `item - item.T`, then sum up the squares of the lower triangle (which I'd have to look up to figure out how to do). You could probably then further improve the performance by figuring out a way to only calculate the lower triangle in the first place. The typical trick to this is figuring out how to get the lower-triangle sum into the diagonal as part of the vectorized operation, and then you just extract the diagonal, but that isn't always appropriate. See [the broadcasting docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for some ideas on how to vectorize the inner loop without creating explicit matrices. Finally, see if there's a way you can create a 3D array out of the whole thing (which may mean padding the individual items out to a fixed width) and then vectorizing the whole operation. (The memory use won't be nearly as bad, as `numpy` only needs to allocate 4 bytes for each value instead of a whole `PyObject`… but it may still be bad enough that you lose more than you gain.) Sorry if this is all a little vague, but hopefully it's enough to get you started on the experimentation.

Another thought is that you can probably parallelize this. Any machine with enough memory to handle that massive list, I'm willing to bet it has at least 4 cores on it. And you've got a long sequence of completely independent operations, which is the easiest thing in the world to parallelize. As a first step, create a `multiprocessing.Pool`, and make the outer loop submit jobs to the pool instead of doing the work directly. You'll probably find that the jobs are too small, so you're drowning in overhead, but then you can always batch up each N items (either explicitly, or see the `grouper` recipe in the `itertools` docs), and make the job be "loop over these N items, and return the one with the min LSD". (It may take some tweaking to find the optimal N.) You can even do this together with the top-level `numpy`, by splitting the giant array up into chunks along the x axis and farming those out as jobs.

One more thought: Your algorithm is starting with a product of N*M, each element of which is of length N. Then, for each element, you loop over it twice. So, the best possible performance is going to be O(N^3*M). Is this really the right algorithm? If so, are you actually getting N^3*M performance from your algorithm? If the answer to either question is no, you shouldn't be trying to micro-optimize it. Only when you've actually got the most efficient algorithm, coded properly, is it worth doing things like vectorizing, avoiding excess work, moving tight loops into C++ and Fortran, etc. Otherwise, you're just going to come back and say "But it still blows up when I go to 4x as big as my last test run".

Comment: It still blow... just kidding. Your code it's a bit faster. I will think some more about the points you stated and try to optimize it.

Comment: Yes, it still blows. :) The iterator is probably only going to improve things by 5-10% if you're not running into swap thrash (although it'll obviously improve things a lot more if you are), and the other ideas aren't actually code you can run… But hopefully it's helpful anyway.

Comment: Can I ask you what do you mean by 'swap trash'?

Comment: Swap thrash means that the computer is doing more work moving virtual memory back and forth to swap files on disk than actually working.

Comment: +1 - that was a very enlightening answer for a novice like me.

Comment: Thanks. Lot's of new concepts for today. I usually use a 8 core machine with 60GB RAM or more. I think I have to focus in one strategy. What do you think I should focus to learn, numpy or cython?

Comment: Well, in the long run, you probably want to learn both. If you don't have time for both, learn `numpy` if you plan to do a lot of numeric stuff with all different kinds of algorithms, `cython` if you plan to do a lot of algorithms with very tight loops with all kinds of data. For a quick&dirty solution for today, if `pip install cython` and following the basic tutorial doesn't run you into any brick walls, I'd try that first, because cythonizing the inner loop is so simple, and may be good enough.

Answer (score 2):

THe first thing I would do would be to put as much of this as you can in Numpy arrays. Array based operations in Numpy are executed at more or less C speed. It looks like much of this could be done in Numpy to begin with...

If that doesn't get your blood flowing, then I would profile the code, and create a function in Cython for the bottel neck. Assuming that you could put a static type on the lists / arrays, Cython is probably going to be your best bet if you want to stay in the Pythonic world. I've personally seen 100x speedups for some bottlenecks using Cython.

Here's an example of [an image convolution with Cython](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html#the-first-cython-program)  from their docs.

Comment: +1. I agree with all of this, although I think the trick here is to figure out _how_ to `numpy` it. His basic structure is a jagged array, which `numpy` isn't great at without help. The inner loop works on the cartesian product of each row with itself, which you can do in `numpy`, but it isn't trivial. (And maybe it would be better to generate a 3D array in the first place, to make it trivial?) Still, I think the OP will probably get more benefit thinking through how to benefit from `numpy` than almost anything else he could think about here, so this is a great answer.

Comment: I'm reading what's Numpy arrays about. Sounds interesting. I'm just an amateur programmer :)

Comment: @biojl, I would start with trying to do the while / for / dist() loop with numpy. I bet that would get you a few X speedup. Loops are slow in Python, double loops are real slow!

Comment: An amateur programmer with a bit of `numpy` knowledge is often a better thing than an expert programmer without it… which is why people who do, e.g., physics or economics for a living love it, because they don't want to become expert programmers.

Comment: Also, good idea on the Cython. It's not always the right tool for the job, but in this case, when all the time is spent doing very little work inside a tight double loop, and when the little work that is being done could be sped up by switching from `PyObject`s to `int`s, it might be almost as much benefit as `numpy` for a whole lot less thinking.