# Least square difference among items of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I just started learning some numpy because of [High performance calculation of least squares difference from all possible combinations (n lists)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731200/high-performance-calculation-of-least-squares-difference-from-all-possible-combi/13731622#comment18867669_13731622):

Right now I'm stucked with the calculations and could use some help.

I have a numpy array object that looks like this:

```
>>> items
array([[ 246, 1143, 1491, ..., 1167,  325, 1158],
       [ 246, 1143, 1491, ..., 1167,  519, 1158],
       [ 246, 1143, 1491, ..., 1167,  507, 1158],
       ..., 
       [1491, 1143,  246, ..., 1167,  325, 1158],
       [1491, 1143,  246, ..., 1167,  519, 1158],
       [1491, 1143,  246, ..., 1167,  507, 1158]])
```

I would like to get the number of the array with the least square difference among all his members, a numpythonic version of:

```
for num,item in enumerate(items): #Calculate for each list of items
      for n in range(len(item)):
        for i in range(n, len(item)):
          dist += (item[n]-item[i])**2 #Key formula
          if dist>min_dist: #This is a shortcut
              break
          else:
              continue
          break               
      if min_dist is None or dist < min_dist:
        min_dist = dist
        best = num #We get the number of the combination we want
```

I would appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your `NxM` array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> items = np.random.random_sample((10,3))
```

Calculate the sum of squares between all elements of each of `N` `M`-dimensional vectors and store the results in a list:

```
>>> sq = [(np.subtract.outer(item,item) ** 2).sum() for item in items]
```

Find the index of the vector with the smallest sum-of-squares between all its elements:

```
>>> best_index = np.argmin(sq)
```

Or, to avoid the intermediate list:

```
best = np.inf
best_index = None
for i,item in enumerate(items):
    ls = (np.subtract.outer(item,item) ** 2).sum()
    if ls < best:
        best = ls
        best_index = i
```

Comment: Do you think is possible to include a similar shortcut that the one I used in my code? We don't really need to finish the calculations of the whole vector if it already has a bigger sum than best.

Comment: Not with this approach. All the work you were doing in your two inner loops is happening in `(np.subtract.outer(item,item) ** 2).sum()`, so there's no way to stop those calculations early.  First a `MxM` array is computed containing the pair-wise differences, then all of those numbers are squared, and then that result is summed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
[(lambda(x):np.square(np.dot(x,-1*x)))(x) for x in items]
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you further develop what it does this one-liner. I'm trying to learn numpy. I'm getting a huge series of numbers comma separated, are those equivalent to my dist? If so how can I get the smallest one and It's correspondent list number position?

Comment: the one liner returns a list where each element is the result of applying the lambda function to each array in items.  the lambda function just does a dot product of each array with -1 times the same array and then squares the results.